# C# MergeField in footer not Working

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am new to C#.  I am attempting to simply use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

All is working except that the Merge Fields in the footer are not updating.  I continue to get the mergecode text only («pname»).

Here is the important part of my code

```
private void getDoc()
    {
        String cdir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        btnGetPoa.Visible = false;
        var application = new Word.Application();
        Object dir = @"../../templates/";
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(dir.ToString());
        var doc = new Word.Document();
        var dirf = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\poas.docx";
        doc = application.Documents.Add(Template: dirf);

        foreach (Word.Field fld in doc.Fields)
        {
            if(fld.Code.Text.Contains("pname"))
            {
                fld.Select();
                application.Selection.TypeText(txtpName.Text.ToString());
            }
        }

        object what = Word.WdGoToItem.wdGoToPage;
        object which = Word.WdGoToDirection.wdGoToFirst;
        object count = 3;
        object missing = Missing.Value;
        application.Selection.GoTo(ref what, ref which, ref count, ref missing);
        application.Visible = true;
        }
```

Any ideas why the Fields in the Footer are not merging?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Document object addresses only the main document "story". So querying fields in that object doesn't "see" any fields in headers, footers, Shapes, etc. You need to specifically address these other objects. For a general method on how to address all StoryRange objects, look at the VBA Language Reference example for StoryRange and related. You'll also find discussions and code on this site.

For your specific request, I'm assuming that the document has only the one section and the standard footer - no first page footer or even page footer. (A Word document can have multiple sections and different types of headers and footers, but a "plain vanilla" document has only one of each.)

```
Word.Range rngFooter = doc.Sections[1].Footers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
foreach (Word.Field fld in rngFooter.Fields)
{
}
```